# implement an automated check of the MD5 hash of uploaded images to avoid duplicated images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, md5

How can I implement automated check of the MD5 hash of uploaded images to avoid duplicated images?

I want to prevent users to avoid uploading duplicated image in my rails application. I have two models named `ImageHash` and `Image` and they have `ono-to-one` relationship. Image model will take care of uploading image on amazon server. I want to check if the image is duplicated. That's why I planned to make md5 hash of binary image in `Imagehash` model. How can I easily implement this ruby on rails.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the MD5 hash in a field on the `Image` model and validate its uniqueness:

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  validates :md5_hash, uniqueness: true
end
```